# ppm tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

[ppm](/questions/tagged/ppm): This tag can mean:

- Perl Package Manager
- Portable Pixmap (a Netpbm image format)

I think it should be divided into two tags: [perl-ppm](/questions/tagged/perl-ppm) and [ppm-format](/questions/tagged/ppm-format) for example.

Comment: How about spelling out both?

Comment: There is already a tag [tag:package-managers] so is it a good idea to have similar tags for multiple languages?

Comment: `perl-ppm` is redundant.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: That's not correct, it should be "is it a good idea to have similar tags for different programs?" which can be answered with yes. That it is the Perl Package Manager only means that it manages packages for the Perl environment, and there could also be others doing the same thing.

Comment: It obviously stands for parts per million.